# Can the encoding difference for printable characters between utf-8 and Latin-1 be resolved?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I read that there should be no difference between Latin-1 and UTF-8 for printable characters. I thought that a latin-1 `'Ä'` would map twice into utf-8.
Once to the Multi byte Version and once directly.

Why does it seem like this is not the case?

It certainly seems like the standard could include anything that looks like a continuation byte but is not a continuation as the meaning within latin-1 without loosing anything.

Am I just missing a flag or something that would allow me to convert the data like described, or am I missing the bigger picture?

Here is a C# example:

The output on my system is

[image]

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DecodeTest("ascii7", " ~", new byte[] { 0x20, 0x7E });
        DecodeTest("Latin-1", "Ä", new byte[] { 0xC4 });
        DecodeTest("UTF-8", "Ä", new byte[] { 0xc3, 0x84 });
    }

    private static void DecodeTest(string testname, string expected, byte[] encoded)
    {
        var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        string ascii7_actual = utf8.GetString(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
        //Console_Write(encoded);
        AssertEqual(testname, expected, ascii7_actual);
    }

    private static void AssertEqual(string testname, string expected, string actual)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test: " + testname);
        if (actual != expected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tFail");
            Console.WriteLine("\tExpected: '" + expected + "' but was '" + actual + "'");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tPass");
        }
    }

    private static void Console_Write(byte[] ascii7_encoded)
    {
        bool more = false;
        foreach (byte b in ascii7_encoded)
        {
            if (more)
            {
                Console.Write(", ");
            }
            Console.Write("0x{0:X}", b);
            more = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no "direct" version of Ä. All codepoints above 127 are encoded with 2 or more bytes in UTF-8. As `Ä` is outside ASCII range obviously it'll be at least 2 bytes. What can have different versions is that you can encoded it in [composed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) or [precomposed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) depending on normalization form you choose

Comment: Whatever you read was nonsense, you discovered it was.  You'll only ever convert 0xC4 to 'Ä' when you use the proper encoding.  There are *many* 8-bit encodings but using codepage 1252 or Encoding.Default tends to be right choice for somebody named Johannes.

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc : String are composed of either one or two bytes (not 2 or more bytes).  ASCII characters (0 to 255) have the MSB set to zero.  Strings and characters are two byte objects with a private property indicating if a character is one or two bytes.  Encoding class can set the private property properly to either one or two bytes.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. There's no difference between **ASCII** and UTF-8. Latin1 / ISO-8895-1, however, maps to Unicode **points**. E.g. `Ä` = "U+00C4" in Unicode, `0xc3 0x84` in UTF-8, `0xc4` in 'windows-1252' and 'latin1/iso-8895-1'

Comment: @jdweng In **UTF-8** characters are stored in 1 byte if the codepoint fits within ASCII space, otherwise it's encoded in 2-4 bytes. About C# string it's 1 or 2 UTF-16 **code units** (2/4 bytes). There's no way to make 1-byte UTF-16 character as you said. And with UTF-8/16 there's no need to indicate the character length anywhere because it's self-contained in the encoding. Do you really think they'll use another array as the property to store the length of each character in that string? Read about character set and character encoding first

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks - could you copy your comments into an answer so I can accept it? I can see the points made in the comments and I think they are correct. I learned something from them.

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc : Did you ever look at the microsoft net encoded output files.  Your definition of UTF doesn't match the way Microsoft net libraries work.

Comment: @jdweng Microsoft doesn't define UTF-8/16/32 encoding, that's the job of Unicode consortium. The output is the same on all platforms. If the output is difffent from UTF-8 then of course it's not a UTF-8 file or you have wrote your code incorectly. Again I suggest reading what UTF-8 and UTF-16 are. And also learn how to tag on stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that there should be no difference between Latin-1 and UTF-8 for printable characters.

You read wrong. There is no difference between Latin-1 (and many other encodings including the rest of the ISO 8859 family) and UTF-8 for characters in the US-ASCII range (U+0000 to U+007F). They are different for **all** other characters.

> I thought that a latin-1 'Ä' would map twice into utf-8. Once to the Multi byte Version and once directly.

For this to be possible would require UTF-8 to be stateful or to otherwise use information earlier in the stream to know whether to interpret an octet as a direct mapping or part of the multibyte encoding. One of the great advantages of UTF-8 is that it is not stateful.

> Why does it seem like this is not the case?

Because it's just plain wrong.

> It certainly seems like the standard could include anything that looks like a continuation byte but is not a continuation as the meaning within latin-1 without losing anything.

It couldn't do so without loosing the quality of not being stateful, which would mean corruption would destroy the entire text following the error rather than just one character.

> Am I just missing a flag or something that would allow me to convert the data like described, or am I missing the bigger picture?

No, you just have a completely incorrect idea about how UTF-8 and/or Latin-1 works.

A flag would remove UTF-8's simplicity in being non-stateful and self-synchronising (you can always tell immediately if you are at a single-octet character, the start of a character or part-way into a character) as mentioned above. It would also remove UTF-8's simplicity in being algorithmic. All UTF-8 encodings map as follows.

To map from code-point to encoding:

1. Consider the bits of the character `xxxx…` e.g. for `U+0027` they are `100111` for `U+1F308` they are `11111001100001000`.
2. Find the smallest of the following they will fit into:

   0xxxxxxx

   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx

   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

   11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

So `U+0027` is `00100111` is `0x27` and `U+1F308` is `11110000 10011111 10001100 10001000` is `0xF0 0x9F 0x8C 0x88`.

To go from octets to code-points you undo this.

To map to Latin 1 you just put the character into a octet, (which obviously only works if they are in the range U+0000 to U+00FF).

As you can see, there's no way that a character outside of the range `U+0000` to `U+007F` can have matching encodings in UTF-8 and Latin-1. ("Latin 1" is also the name of CP-1252 which is a Microsoft encoding that puts further printable characters but still only a tiny fraction of those covered by UTF-8).

There is a way that a character could theoretically have more than one UTF-8 encoding, but it is explicitly banned. Consider that instead of putting the bits of `U+0027` into the single unit `00100111` we could also zero-pad and put it into `11000000 10100111` encoding it as `0xC0 0xA7`. The same decoding algorithm would bring us back to `U+0027` (try it and see). However as well as introducing needless complexity in having such synonym encodings this also introduced security issues and indeed there have been real-world security holes caused by code that would accept over-long UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need a scan-function to descide which decoder is required?

try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Count valid UTF8-Bytes
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// -1 = invalid UTF8-Bytes (may Latin1)
/// 0 = ASCII only 7-Bit
/// n = Count of UTF8-Bytes
/// </returns>
public static int Utf8CodedCharCounter(byte[] value) // result: 
{
  int utf8Count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
  {
    byte c = value[i];
    if ((c & 0x80) == 0) continue; // valid 7 Bit-ASCII -> skip

    if ((c & 0xc0) == 0x80) return -1; // wrong UTF8-Char

    // 2-Byte UTF8
    i++; if (i >= value.Length || (value[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) return -1; // wrong UTF8-Char
    if ((c & 0xe0) == 0xc0) { utf8Count++; continue; }

    // 3-Byte UTF8
    i++; if (i >= value.Length || (value[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) return -1; // wrong UTF8-Char
    if ((c & 0xf0) == 0xe0) { utf8Count++; continue; }

    // 4-Byte UTF8
    i++; if (i >= value.Length || (value[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) return -1; // wrong UTF8-Char
    if ((c & 0xf8) == 0xf0) { utf8Count++; continue; }

    return -1; // invalid UTF8-Length
  }
  return utf8Count;
}
```

and update your code:

```
private static void DecodeTest(string testname, string expected, byte[] encoded)
{
  var decoder = Utf8CodedCharCounter(encoded) >= 0 ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.Default;
  string ascii7_actual = decoder.GetString(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
  //Console_Write(encoded);
  AssertEqual(testname, expected, ascii7_actual);
}
```

result:

```
Test: ascii7
        Pass
Test: Latin-1
        Pass
Test: UTF-8
        Pass
```